# Avoid spinup of secondary harddrive upon resume from suspend

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, suspend

I've just installed an extra handdrive. I intend to store movies etc on it, so it will be seldom used.

When I suspend or resume the harddrive spins up, even if the drive is unmounted. Is there a way to avoid this?

(I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to the usb drivers strobing the usb ports checking for active devices during the state change operation.  I have an external drive that does the same thing... it will occasionally fire up when I insert a flash drive or whatnot into another port on the computer.  Something about the 'check who's there' operation wakes up the drive.